# Extracting substrings within the JSON using the Jetpacks

Tags: json, postman

I am using the Postman App with the jetpacks plugin and want to set envVar or globalVar within my tests based off a href response I get.

```
{
     href: "http://api.alpha.com/profiles//8a5c7d62332067b48473350171ba4206"
}
```

So in my test box I've entered the flowing code to extract and set the profile_id variable yet it goes unset.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("profile_Id", data.substring(37));
```

Does this functionality exist within the Jetpacks plugin for postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this functionality is available.

The correct way to achieve the functionalitly is:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("profile_Id", data.href.substring(37));
```

The JSON.parse function turns the reponseBody into a javascript object.  You need to then retrieve the href property from that javascript object.

The code above will set environment variable of profile_Id to 8a5c7d62332067b48473350171ba4206.

You can then use the following syntax to reference the profile_id {{profile_Id}}.

More details can be found [here](http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/)